# Finding the sum of prime numbers between m and n (m and n included in the sum)

Tags: python

```
def isPrime(n, i):
    if i == n-1:
        return ("True")
    elif n%i == 0:
        return ("False")
    else:
        return isPrime(n, i+1)

def sumOfPrime(m,n):
    if m > 0 and n > 0 and m <= n:
      if isPrime(m,2)==True:
        temp = temp + m
        return temp
      else:
        return (sumOfPrime(m+1,n))
    else:
      return temp
```

how can I fix the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment" without using a global variable

Comment: could I do it without using a global variable?

Comment: Also, isPrime() returns the _strings_ "True" or "False", but sumOfPrime() is checking for the _boolean value_ True, which is not the same thing.

Comment: yes, but you need to pass the sum as an attribute in the function(I didn't realise you have temp as global)

can you show your remaining code too?

Comment: Is it currently a global?  If so, you haven't shown us that.

Comment: could you show me how I could fix it? I am really lost

Comment: @ManikaSharma It won't take garbage as this is Python. Python just raises exception if an undefined variable is accessed. The thing that you are pointing to is done by C and C++.

Comment: Apologies, I will edit my comment

Comment: @MariaFlores: Don't delete the main body of your question just because it's been answered, it renders it completely useless for people who find it later. I've rolled it back to the version with your actual broken code (that's actually answerable).

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code, and this is my proposal:

```
def isPrime(n, i=None):
    if i is None:
        i = n - 1
    while i >= 2:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return isPrime(n, i-1)
    else:
        return True

def sumOfPrime(m, n):
    sum = 0
    for value in range(m, n+1):
        if isPrime(value):
            sum = sum + value
    return sum


# --- test ---
result = sumOfPrime(1, 9)
print (result) # <-- prints 18
```

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between `m` and `n` is quite high, then it is recommended that you use some type of sieve, to filter primes out in a given range. Otherwise, iterating over numbers from `m` to `n` and checking if the number is prime, it is going to be expensive for large `m` and `n`.

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return n > 1
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def prime_range_sum(m, n):
    return sum(i for i in range(m, n + 1) if is_prime(i))


print(prime_range_sum(1, 9))
# prints 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, which I kept as close as possible to the original, while fixing some errors and making some adjustments.

```
def isPrime(n, i=2):    # since you always use 2, just make it default
    if i == n-1:
        return True     # return a boolean True instead of a string
    elif n%i == 0:
        return False    # return a boolean False instead of a string
    else:
        return isPrime(n, i+1)

   
def sumOfPrime(m,n,total=0):    # we will need to carry the total around, make default to 0
    if 0 < m <= n:              # we can simplify this complex condition
        if isPrime(m):
            total += m              # if it's prime, increase the total...
        return sumOfPrime(m+1, n, total)   # and pass it to the next recursion
    return total               # if this is the last recursion, return total


# Example run
total = sumOfPrime(10,45)
print(total)    # prints 264
```